# Is freezing jeans a substitute for cleaning them with soap and water?

Tags: clothing, cleaning

It is a common household tip: Put your jeans in the freezer to freshen them up. Denim enthusiasts [claim it will kill bacteria](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/how-to-clean-your-jeans-withou-109266) (although it won't remove stains). Is this true? Is it hygienic to forgo normal cleaning for jeans?

Comment: Just as a side remark: if you want to have hygienic _cushions_, then deep-freezing is more effective than washing to get rid of _house dust mites_. (I read that washing with 40° C will just give you _clean_ mites `:-)`)

Comment: Don't forget there's more to cleaning than killing bacteria. I doubt freezing the jeans would help remove dirt stains.

Comment: @Rahzark - If you dont want the dirt off just want them not to smell though... you know for the cowboy look with out the cowboy smell.

Comment: I would recommend a  UV light bath!, this will kill bacteria for sure!, just dont look at this light!, there are lamps available!

Comment: My side question would be on the increased energy consumption of your freezer because of the high mass to freeze...